# How can I update values in a column based on values on the same column but different rows?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Take the example:

```
> set.seed(42)
> ids <- c("u1", "u2", "u3")
> groups <- c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3))
> reps <- c(rep("r1",9), rep("r2",9), rep("r3",9))
> vals <- rnorm(27, 0, 2)
> 
> df = data.frame(ids = rep(ids, 9), groups = rep(groups,3), reps = reps, vals = vals)
> df
   ids groups reps       vals
1   u1      A   r1  2.7419169
2   u2      A   r1 -1.1293963
3   u3      A   r1  0.7262568
4   u1      B   r1  1.2657252
5   u2      B   r1  0.8085366
6   u3      B   r1 -0.2122490
7   u1      C   r1  3.0230440
8   u2      C   r1 -0.1893181
9   u3      C   r1  4.0368474
10  u1      A   r2 -0.1254282
11  u2      A   r2  2.6097393
12  u3      A   r2  4.5732908
13  u1      B   r2 -2.7777214
14  u2      B   r2 -0.5575775
15  u3      B   r2 -0.2666427
16  u1      C   r2  1.2719008
17  u2      C   r2 -0.5685058
18  u3      C   r2 -5.3129108
19  u1      A   r3 -4.8809339
20  u2      A   r3  2.6402267
21  u3      A   r3 -0.6132772
22  u1      B   r3 -3.5626169
23  u2      B   r3 -0.3438347
24  u3      B   r3  2.4293494
25  u1      C   r3  3.7903869
26  u2      C   r3 -0.8609383
27  u3      C   r3 -0.5145388
```

What I want to do is to subtract the mean of values in C.r1, C.r2 and C.r3 for each id. The idea is to use group C as a baseline for the other groups.

So in terms of expected outcome, for the first two rows:

- (u1, A, r1) should be modified as 2.74 - mean(3.02, 1.27, 3.79) =
  0.046
- (u2, A, r1) should be modified as -1.23 - mean(-0.18, -0.56, -0.86) =
  -0.69

How can I get this to work on all rows in a large (about 1M rows) table that contains a number of other columns besides the relevant ones here? I obviously need to group by `ids` but the look up of values that match specifically `group == C` together with mean of of vals is a bit tricky.

```
> dt <- setDT(df)
> dt[groups == "C", cmean := mean(vals), ids]
```

gives me the means of group C measurements for each id (in multiple copies), but I cannot really use those values immediately, since all the other rows are already filtered out. I think I might need to chain somehow but I am not sure how exactly.

I would be equally interested in solutions with `data.table` and `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a join after subsetting for 'groups' that are 'C', grouped by 'ids', get the `mean` of 'vals', then we join the original dataset `on` the 'ids', subtract the 'vals' from the first dataset with the 'Meanvals' from the second and assign (`:=`) it to 'newvals'

```
setDT(df)[df[groups=="C", .(Meanvals = mean(vals)), ids], 
                         newvals := vals - Meanvals, on = .(ids)]
head(df)
```

Comment: It works, but I have no idea why :) Could you explain a bit maybe? Doesn't the "subsetting" return a data.table in this case? How can you use a data.table inside the `i` statement of the same data table index?

Comment: @posdef Yes, it does subset it, but when we are joining `on` with the original dataset by 'ids', the 'Meanvals' repeat itself for each corresponding 'ids' and this can be subtracted.  Here, we are using joining `X[Y, on = .(grouping variable)]`

Comment: I see, would it be possible to avoid modifying the original table `dt` and return a modified copy a la `dplyr`?

Comment: @posdef  You can use `df1 <- copy(df)` then apply the code on `df1`

Answer (score 1):

One possible `dplyr`-solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ids) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(vals[groups=="C"]), 
         vals = vals - mean) %>% select(-mean)

# A tibble: 27 × 4
      ids groups   reps        vals
   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>       <dbl>
1      u1      A     r1  0.04680632
2      u2      A     r1 -0.58980895
3      u3      A     r1  1.32312422
4      u1      B     r1 -1.42938536
5      u2      B     r1  1.34812404
```